# Python:Some special method for escaping single quotes and double quotes from a string variable

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I am inputting a variable of datatype string in Sqlite database with my Python script.So whenever i am inserting that value i am getting Sqlite error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error
```

My variable string is something like this:

```
file_path=r'James Bond 007 - 07 - On Her Majesty's Secret Service (1969)'
```

Actually i am getting this file name directly from `os.walk` so i can't  escape that single string by putting backslash manually.I want some string method which automatically escapes the content inside string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT ... (?, ?, ?)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

Comment: I had already  written my queries exactly like this which you hav mentioned but the error is occuring because of a unescaped quote inside that variable .Which i am not finding any way to escape it.

Comment: +1: Why are people still doing raw query construction without placeholders?

Comment: @FlorianBrucker: easy, because a file with SQL statements can be read and understood and can contain comments. That's a tad bit harder for a binary SQLite3 database. And using something to the effect of the `.dump` command of the `sqlite3` command line utility will also strip any comments. Why are people checking *source code* into their version control system and not the binaries? Same reason here for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using a forward slash seems to work for me but I haven't had any trouble with single quotes.

So:

```
"\"this seems to work fine.\""
```